# How to display data in blade laravel blade with html tag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, trumbowyg

I am using a WYSIWG functionality in my application which works fine. And my problem now is in displaying its data in the user side. I'm trying to use `{!! !!}` but has no luck on making it work. This is my two data types the first one works with `{!! !!}` and the other one does not:

**Works**

```
<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor asdjfgjasfgbjgj
gjbhgjgjgjkghkj; lkfakj ;ljljfl sdfadfasfd asera
        <br>sdjfhgbkjhb jhgasfd <br><img src="https://instagram.fmnl4- 
4.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/9cc3e3163fa4c45e36ba06dab80a2a8b/5D0C4134/t51.2885- 
15/e35/52578723_295046217837106_4438462673106962420_n.jpg? 
_nc_ht=instagram.fmnl4-4.fna.fbcdn.net" height="500" width="500"></p> <br> 
jdsfa bygjhsdg jkbv kjbv lvkbsal lkjb nlknasdkfl lkjbokhbkldjskljbhjlkhkjhkl  
kjlkd aslkh l<br> jhasgdf jhdgywaegrhbkihn kjb klaSNDfckhb kjaghdfjbkjh 
<br>adsf knihlkh lk j ojlojjk <h1>fg lknhl kh lkuh adji3wij;oji voi npo ; 
posdjfopijnpaiywer <h1>
```

**NOT**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
    <html><body><p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor <strong>asdjfgjasfgbjgj </strong>gjbhgjgjgjkghkj; lkfakj ;ljljfl sdfadfasfd asera
                <br>sdjfhgbkjhb jhgasfd <br><img src="https://instagram.fmnl4-4.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/9cc3e3163fa4c45e36ba06dab80a2a8b/5D0C4134/t51.2885-15/e35/52578723_295046217837106_4438462673106962420_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fmnl4-4.fna.fbcdn.net" height="500" width="500"></p> <br><p> jdsfa bygjhsdg jkbv kjbv lvkbsal lkjb nlknasdkfl lkjbokhbkldjskljbhjlkhkjhkl  kjlkd aslkh l</p><p> jhasgdf jhdgywaegrhbkihn kjb klaSNDfckhb kjaghdfjbkjh </p><p>adsf knihlkh lk j ojlojjk </p><h1>fg lknhl kh lkuh adji3wij;oji voi npo ; posdjfopijnpaiywer </h1><h1></h1></body></html>
```

I parsed them this way:

```
{!! substr($new ->content, 0, 70) !!}
```

And there result is like this:

[image]

The second one is working in using the blade unescaped tag. I want them to be both displaying first 70 characters only. I'm using Laravel trumbowyg WYSIWG plugin. Someone know how to display it in blade php?

Comment: What are you wanting the substring of 70 characters to look like? When you run `substr($new->content, 0, 70)` on HTML, it's going to return the first 70 characters of the HTML, not of the rendered text. That means you'll likely end up with broken HTML, as you'll get opening tags without the corresponding closing tags.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for pointing that out. How can I exclude tags in blade?

Comment: @EemJee, [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

Comment: Gyrocode.com's answer is probably the best solution if you want to remove HTML entirely. Note that you'll lose any formatting when you get the substring though.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Thanks. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to by pass blade's limitations you should use @php  @phpend and write your plain PHP code in there.